# No me carga la data en useEffect react (solo cuando guardo cambios)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Escribo por si alguien ha pasado ya por lo mismo, result que estoy usando react paginate para crear una paginacion [aca la documentacion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate)

Tome el ejemplo y lo adapte a mi caso. **El problema** es que cuando carga por primera vez no me carga la informacion, se que funciona bien la paginacion **por que solo funciona cuando hago cambios en el codigo y guardo (ctrl+s)**

Yo asumo que el error tal vez esta en el tiempo que se demora la api en responder porque cuando, sin embargo ya he intentado usar promesas y muchas otras soluciones.

Entonces **en resumen** para que se entienda mas claro:

> Consumo un endpoint que me entrega un arreglo de informacion que guardo en la const `Avisos` usando el hook del estado, con el segundo `useEffect()` lo que se hace es dividir el arreglo `Avisos` con el hook `setCurrentItems()`, `currentItems` finalmente son los items que se muestran en la primera pagina.

[image: Imagen cuando carga por primera vez la pagina]
En la imagen de arriba es la consola cuando carga por primera vez la pagina

[image: Imagen despues de guardar]

La imagen de arriba es cuando hago cambios en el codigo y guardo esos cambios (ctrl+s)

Vengo con este problema de hace rato, he probado con usar solo un `useEffect`, he cambiado las dependencias del `useEffect`, he intentado usar promesas, async await.

```
    `iimport React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import {getUrlApi, peticionAxios,getUrlImages} from "../../Funciones.js"
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faComments, faEye, faHandshake, faMagnifyingGlass, faEraser} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import {Link}  from "react-router-dom"
import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content'
import RegionesComponent from '../Regiones'


export default function ListadoAvisos(props, { itemsPerPage=6 }){
    const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal)

let ruta = getUrlImages(),json = null
const iconComments = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faComments} color="orange" size="lg"/>
const iconViews = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEye} color="blue" />
const iconHands = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHandshake} color="green"/>
const iconBuscar = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMagnifyingGlass} />
const iconBorrar = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEraser} />
let method = "GET"
const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
const idUsuario = localStorage.getItem("id")
const [Avisos,setAvisos] = useState([])
const [estados,setEstados] = useState([])
const [categorias,setCategorias] = useState([])
//Empezamos con una lista vacia
const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState(null);
const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
const [itemOffset, setItemOffset] = useState(0);

const [filtroTitulo,setFiltroTitulo] = useState("")
const [filtroComuna,setFiltroComuna] = useState(0)
const [filtroEstado,setFiltroEstado] = useState(0)
const [filtroCategorias,setFiltroCategorias] = useState(0)


useEffect(() => {
    cargarComboEstados()
    cargarComboCategorias()
    buscarAvisos()
    
},[])

//useState de paginacion
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Avisosssss",Avisos)
    const endOffset = itemOffset + itemsPerPage;
    setCurrentItems(Avisos.slice(itemOffset, endOffset));
    setPageCount(Math.ceil(Avisos.length / itemsPerPage));
}, [itemOffset, itemsPerPage]);
//funcion para cuando cambian de pagina
const handlePageClick = (event) => {
    const newOffset = (event.selected * itemsPerPage) % Avisos.length;
    console.log(
    `Se solicito la pagina ${event.selected}, which is offset ${newOffset}`
    );
    setItemOffset(newOffset);
};


const buscarAvisos = async()=>{
    
    let url = getUrlApi()
    let urlAvisos
    (!props.MisAvisos)? urlAvisos= url+"avisos" : urlAvisos = url+`avisos/idUser/${idUsuario}`
    
    if(props.MisAvisos){
        json = {
            idUsuario:idUsuario
        }
    }

    await peticionAxios(urlAvisos,method,token,json).then(
        res=>{
            setAvisos(res.data.Avisos)
        }
    ).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        }
    )
}
const buscarAvisosFiltrado = ()=>{
    setFiltroTitulo(document.getElementById("txtTituloFiltro").value)
    setFiltroEstado(document.getElementById("sltFiltroEstado").value)
    setFiltroCategorias(document.getElementById("sltFiltroCategoria").value)
    setFiltroComuna(document.getElementById("sltComuna").value)
    buscarAvisos()
}
const cargarComboEstados = ()=>{
    let urlObtenerEstados = `${getUrlApi()}obtenerEstados`
    peticionAxios(urlObtenerEstados,'GET',token).then(res=>{
        if(res.status == 200){
           setEstados(res.data) 
        }
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.error("Ha ocurrido un errro al cargar los estados")
        console.log(err)
    })
}
const cargarComboCategorias = ()=>{
    let urlcategorias  = `${getUrlApi()}categorias`
    peticionAxios(urlcategorias,method,token, "").then(resultado=>{
        if(resultado.status ==200){
            setCategorias(resultado.data)     
        }else{
            console.log("Ha ocurrido un error", resultado)
        }
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
}
const dibujarEstado = (estados)=>{
    let estadoActual = estados.find(x=>x.pivot.activo===1)
    
    if(estadoActual!==undefined){
        let color = ""
        switch(estadoActual.descripcionEstado){
            case "Abierta":
                color =`success`
                break
            case "Cerrada":
                color =`danger`
                break
            case "Desierta":
                color = `secondary`
                break
            case "Eliminada":
                color = `dark`
                break
            default:
                color = `danger`
                break
        }
        return <span className={`btn btn-${color} btn-sm`}>{estadoActual.descripcionEstado}</span>
    }
}

function Items({ currentItems }) {
    console.info(currentItems)
    return (
        <>
          {currentItems &&
            currentItems.map((item) => (
                <div key={item.id} className='col-md-4 p-3'>
                <div>
                <div className="card">
                    <div className='card-header'>
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className="col-md-8">
                                <b>Subido por: </b>{item.name}
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-4">
                            {dibujarEstado(item.estados)}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <div className='row'>
                            
                            <div className='col-md-12'>
                                {item.imagen!==null?
                                    <img className="card-img-top imageAviso" src={ruta + item.imagen} alt="Card image cap"/>
                                    :""
                                }
                            </div>
                            <div className='col-md-12'>
                                <h4 className="card-title">{item.titulo}</h4>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div className='col-md-12'>
                                <span><b>Ubicacion:</b>{item.nombreCiudad}, {item.nombreComuna}</span>
                            </div>
                            <p className="card-text">{item.descripcion}</p>
                            <div className='col-md-4'>
                            {iconComments} : {item.valoraciones.length}  
                            </div>
                            <div className='col-md-4'>
                            {iconViews} : {item.vistas??0}
                            </div>
                            <div className='col-md-4'>
                            {iconHands} : {item.users.length??0}
                            </div>
                            <Link to={`../Aviso/idAviso=${item.id}`} className="btn btn-primary">Más informacion</Link>
                            {/* {botonPostular(item.idUsuario,item.id,item.titulo)} */}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-footer">
                        <div className='row'>
                            <div className='col-md-12'>
                                <span><b>Fecha publicacion:</b> {item.fecha}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            
        </div>
            ))}
        </>
      );
}


if(Avisos.length>0){
    return(
        <div className='row m-2'>
            <div className="col-md-12 col-sm-12 p-2">
            <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
                <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
                    <Accordion.Header><h5 className="text-center">Filtrar busqueda</h5></Accordion.Header>
                    <Accordion.Body>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <label className='w-100'>Buscar por titulo
                                    <input  type="text"
                                    id="txtTituloFiltro" 
                                    className='form-control'
                                    maxLength={30}
                                    placeholder="Busque coincidencias en titulo"></input>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <RegionesComponent/> 
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <label>Estado</label>
                                <select id="sltFiltroEstado" className="form-control">
                                    <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                                    {
                                    estados.length>0?
                                            estados.map(a=>{
                                                return (<option value={a.id} key={a.id}>{a.descripcionEstado}</option>)
                                            })
                                        :""
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                                <label>Categoria</label>
                                <select id="sltFiltroCategoria" className="form-control">
                                    <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                                    {
                                    categorias!==undefined?
                                            categorias.map(a=>{
                                                return (<option value={a.id} key={a.id}>{a.descripcionCategoria}</option>)
                                            })
                                        :""
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div className="col-md-3">
                                    <button className="btn btn-outline-success m-1" onClick={()=>{buscarAvisosFiltrado()}}>{iconBuscar}Buscar</button>
                                    <button className="btn btn-outline-dark m-1">{iconBorrar}Limpiar filtros</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Accordion.Body>
                </Accordion.Item>
            </Accordion>
            </div>
            <div className='col-md-12 mt-2'>
                <div className='row'>
                <>
                
                    <Items currentItems={currentItems} />
                    <ReactPaginate 
                    nextLabel="Siguiente >"
                    onPageChange={handlePageClick}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={3}
                    marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                    pageCount={pageCount}
                    previousLabel="< Anterior"
                    pageClassName="page-item"
                    pageLinkClassName="page-link"
                    previousClassName="page-item"
                    previousLinkClassName="page-link"
                    nextClassName="page-item"
                    nextLinkClassName="page-link"
                    breakLabel="..."
                    breakClassName="page-item"
                    breakLinkClassName="page-link"
                    containerClassName="pagination"
                    activeClassName="active"
                    renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
                    />
                </>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}else{
    return (<><p>Sin avisos por ahora</p></>)
}
```

}`

El codigo de arriba es el codigo de mi componente que tiene el error.

Comment: Pdrías agregar cómo lo has intentado con `async` y `await`?

Comment: Suponiendo que sea por lo que dices de que el api tarda en contestar, podrías probar colocar avisos dentro del segundo useEffect, para que se ejecute cuando ocurra un cambio en avisos, esa podría ser una solución, prueba quitar el el llamado a las api e inicializar los avisos en duro en el codigo para ver si te funciona. Pero sospecho que el problema es que este se ejecuta antes de que el primero finalice y como los avisos no son un disparador entonces no vuelve a levantarse.

Comment: @AlexVarela asi es, justamente lo resolvi de esa forma ayer, en el segundo useEffect coloque en las dependencias Avisos, entonces se ejecuta cuando  la peticion es exitosa y se carga en el estado de `Avisos` se ejecuta perfecta la paginacion, agradezco la atencion de ambos.

Comment: Excelente, me alegra. No olvides agregarlo como respuesta pues puede servirle a alguien en el futuro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo pude resolver pasandole como dependencia el arreglo `Avisos`, de esta forma cuando `Avisos` cambia se ejecuta el useEffect de la paginacion y quedo de la siguiente forma:

```
//useState de paginacion
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Avisosssss",Avisos)
    const endOffset = itemOffset + itemsPerPage;
    setCurrentItems(Avisos.slice(itemOffset, endOffset));
    setPageCount(Math.ceil(Avisos.length / itemsPerPage));
}, [itemOffset, itemsPerPage, Avisos]);
```